# How to use term distances for ranking in Solr/Lucene

Tags: solr, lucene, ranking, scoring

Is it possible to use term distances for ranking in Solr/Lucene? For example when searching for *a b c* a document with the phrase "a b c" should get an higher score than a document that contains all terms but with a larger term distance (a x x x b x x x c), a different order (c b a) or a subset of terms (a b).

I'm aware of [proximity searches](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description) but their influence on the score seems unclear. Do they fulfill my requirements? Since I wan't to search in the complete document, does it make sense to use sth. like 99999 as the proximity (e.g. "a b c"~99999)?

Comment: Maybe try it and see how the score changes?  I would expect the score to go up

Comment: The score increases when terms are more closely together since the proximity counts the terms swaps to perform but from my experience with Solr it is better to know what exactly happens since many functions have unexcpected side effects.

Comment: Also, the proximity operator requires all terms to be present but I want also find documents that contain only a subset of terms (see question).